# One protocol, used by many classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

I understand how to make a class conform to several protocols, but where and how do I define a protocol that will be called by several classes, i.e.

```
_delegate.doStuff
```

could appear in several classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In xcode,

`File-> New File-> Objective-c Protocol`

```
@protocol myProtocolName

- (void) doStuff; 

@end
```

then in classes you want to implement this protocol

```
... 
#import "myProtocol.h"
@interface aClass <myProtocolName>
...
```

You can add this to any number of classes.

Comment: Just to clarify, you simply have a .h file with the protocol. No .m file.

Comment: Oh yes, of course, but if you were to make a new `Objective-c protocol` by the file menu in Xcode it will only generate the files you need i.e: only the header (.h) but thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 2):

Just make a new protocol definition -- usually in a nicely #import'able .h file. In Xcode, this is under File, New, "Objective-C Protocol".

Here's a fun little example of two protocols, and some required and optional methods and properties. Note that properties on protocols *must* be synthesized in classes that conform to the protocol if the property is @required (@required is the default, so it can be left out if there is not @optional section).

```
// AnimalMinionType.h
@protocol AnimalMinionType <NSObject>
@required
@property (nonatomic, getter = isHerbivore) BOOL herbivore;
- (NSString *)genus;
- (NSString *)species;
- (NSString *)nickname;
- (void)doPet;
@optional
- (NSString *)subspecies;
@end

// IdiotType.h
@protocol IdiotType <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)pet:(id<AnimalMinionType>)pet didScratch:(BOOL)scratchy;
@end

// FluffyCat.h
@interface FluffyCat : NSObject <AnimalType>
@end

// FluffyCat.m
@implementation FluffyCat
@synthesize herbivore;
- (NSString *)genus { return @"felis"; }
- (NSString *)species { return @"catus"; }
- (NSString *)nickname { return @"damn cat"; }
- (void)doPet:(id<IdiotType>)anyoneOrAnything
{
    NSLog(@"meow");
    if ([anyoneOrAnything respondsToSelector:@selector(pet:didScratch:)])
        [anyoneOrAnything pet:self didScratch:@YES];
}
@end

// Owner.h
@interface Owner : NSObject <IdiotType>
@property id<AnimalMinionType> housepet;
@end

// Owner.m
@implementation Owner
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.housepet = [FluffyCat new];
        [self.housepet setHerbivore:@NO];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)ohACuteAnimalWhatKindIsIt
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[self.housepet genus], [self.housepet species]];
}

- (void)haveALongDayAtWorkAndJustNeedAFriend
{
    if (self.housepet) [self.housepet doPet:self];
}

- (void)pet:(id<AnimalMinionType>)pet didScratch:(BOOL)scratchy
{
    if ((scratchy) && (pet == self.housepet))
    {
        NSLog(@"I HATE THAT %@", [[self.housepet nickname] uppercaseString]);
        self.housepet = nil;
    }
}
@end
```

I hope that helps. :-)